How to print a tuple's name?
So, I'm quite new to coding. I have 2 tuples, say Tup1 and Tup2, of equal length, and have defined their product tuple as the element-wise product (i.e. prod = (Tup1[i]*Tup2[i] for i in range(len(Tup1)) ).
I would like the code to give me the output in the following format:
Tup1 / Tup2 = prod
So here, Tup1 and Tup2 are actually displayed as the strings, Tup1 and Tup2, the slash just separates them (can honestly be any character), and prod will be displayed as the actual tuple, as defined above.
Any idea how to do this?
Thanks
I have also tried this with a dictionary, defining strings Tup1 and Tup2 as keys to their corresponding tuples, but am also clueless as to how to proceed with this.

Assuming that Tup1 = (1,2,3,4,5) and Tup2 = (2,3,4,5,6), you can do this as below.
Code
Tup1 = (1,2,3,4,5)
Tup2 = (2,3,4,5,6)
prod = (Tup1[i]*Tup2[i] for i in range(len(Tup1)))
print("Tup1/Tup2 =", tuple(prod))

Result
Tup1/Tup2 = (2, 6, 12, 20, 30)

An explanation for beginners
Lines 1 and 2 initialise the two tuples. Line 3 performs the "element-wise product" that you mentioned. In the print statement, the string "Tup1/Tup2 =" is printed (this does not change), along with the value of prod as a tuple. The tuple(prod) function converts the generator function's output (prod) to a tuple. A comma is used to separate the string and the tuple, as they are two different variables of two different datatypes.
I hope that this is what you wanted.
